# Render a page during a custom sequential workflow

Tags: workflow, visual-studio, workflow-activity

I am trying to build a sequential workflow on VS2010 that at some point gets the necessary javascript code to render a page. Let's assume the javascript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var link = document.createElement('div');
    link.innerHTML= "Hello";
</script>
```

So how would I be able to implement this so that when the workflow is finished, it takes me to a page where I can run that javascript?
Any tutorials, or sample code would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Spre3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to. Workflows run on the timer service, independent of the current user, or httpcontext. Some workarounds are to 1) assign a task to the user at completion 2) send email to user from workflow at completion 3) create a view of completed workflows. Any of these will allow the user to access said page after the workflow is complete, but it'll be a manual process.

Comment: In that case would you say using a custom sequential workflow is the best way to do it?
How would I be able to access the javascript code retrieved by the workflow once it is completed?

Comment: What I would do is assign a task to the user, include in the task a link to a custom page which would then have your javascript and anything else.

Comment: I am not sure that is what I am looking for. This javascript generates a page with an interview and I would like that interview to be part of the workflow. Could I create a task that consisted of completing that interview? Maybe have some sort of task form to display the interview or something?

Comment: Yes, you can customize the task form using SharePoint Designer/InfoPath and make it do what you need.